# pymongo aggregate using match after lookup

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I am wondering how I can match after a lookup was made. Test Data looks like:

Main Collection:

```
{
  "_id": "642dabf17787c59db0b56780"
  "field": "value",
  "misc": {
    "field": "value",
  }
}
```

Reference Collection have two documents:

```
{
  "_id": "642dabf17787c59db0b56781",
  "master_id": "642dabf17787c59db0b56780",
  **"unique": "first"**,
  "field": "value",
  "first": [
    {
      "field": "value",
    }
  ],
  "second": [
    {
      "field": "value",
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

```
{
  "_id": "642dad0d5838b1e6e8b1810b",
  "master_id": "642dabf17787c59db0b56780",
  **"unique": "second"**,
  "field": "value",
  "first": [
    {
      "field": "value",
    }
  ],
  "second": [
    {
      "field": "value",
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

My query looks like:

```
db.MasterData.aggregate([
    {
        "$match": {
            "_id": ObjectId("642dabf17787c59db0b56780")
        }
    },
    {
        "$lookup": {
            "from": "RefData",
            "localField": "_id",
            "foreignField": "master_id",
            "as": "RefData"
        }
    },
    {
        "$match": {
            "RefData.unique": "first"
        }
    },
])
```

Resulting in showing both, unique value first and second. I would expect only include the first unique value since the second match should filtering the RefCollection.

Comment: Not fully clear what you mean, but try `{ $set: { RefData: { $first: "$RefData" } } }`

Comment: The output format you want isn't clear, but are you looking for something like this [mongoplayground.net example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/lBua6misLzs)?

Comment: Exactly rickhg, thank you. Sorry next time I will be clearer with the expected output.